# Changing kartik dynagrid action column

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Am using kartik yii2 dynagrid.Am trying to change the action delete actioncolumn but i get an error that

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request
>   methods: POST.

My code :

```
['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn','dropdown'=>false,
    'order'=>DynaGrid::ORDER_FIX_RIGHT,
                      'template'=>'{delete}',
                        'buttons'=>[
                          'delete' => function ($url, $model) {     
           return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>', $url, [
                                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'delete'),
                            ]);                                

                          }
                      ]                            
]
```

The other actions work well but changing the `'template'=>'delete'` but only delete action fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `data-method= "post"` attribute to your anchor tag

```
        'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                  return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>', $url,

                      [  
                         'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'delete'),
                         'data-confirm' => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
                         'data-method' => 'post',
                         'data-pjax' => 0
                      ]);
             }
```